# how to set the default button in a TaskDialog?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, comctl32

I am using TaskDialog API in a win32 app. I created a Task Dialog with YES/NO buttons but I can't find any option to set the No button as default. YES button is always the default. Please let me know if there is a way to set the NO button as default. I know TaskDialogIndirect supports a default button option but its an overkill for what i am trying to do. I just want a simple YES/NO Dialog with NO button as default. I did not want to use the MessageBox API because i don't want a close button in the titlebar.

Thanks,

Abhinay

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
TASKDIALOGCONFIG tc;
```

Set the default button by setting the `nDefaultButton` member, e.g.:

```
tc.nDefaultButton = ...;
```

"This may be any of the values specified in `nButtonID` members of one of the `TASKDIALOG_BUTTON` structures in the `pButtons` array, or one of the IDs corresponding to the buttons specified in the `dwCommonButtons` member:

- `IDCANCEL`    Make the Cancel button the default.
- `IDNO`    Make the No button the default.
- `IDOK`    Make the OK button the default.
- `IDRETRY` Make the Retry button the default.
- `IDYES`   Make the Yes button the default.
- `IDCLOSE` Make the Close button the default."

The above bit [shamelessly quoted from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So basically, if you're using the standard predefined buttons, set the field to one of the above constants; if you're using a custom button, set it to the ID you use when specifying the button.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer given by David, I would add my two cents - If you are using MFC, you may use [CTaskDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293651.aspx) class.